# Create a symfony2 remember me cookie manually (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: symfony, remember-me, fosuserbundle

Could somebody explain how you can manually create a remember me cookie in a controller?

I want the users to stay logged in after they pressed the "register"
button, without having to login with their credentials afterwards.

I've tried to create a cookie manually but i'm guessing the cookie
value is incorrect, and therefor the "remember me" functionality
doesn't work.
A cookie with the correct name gets set. I've checked that.

The remember me functionality works as expected when using the normal
login procedure with the user's credentials.

security.yml
security.yml remember me

```
security:
   firewalls:
       main:
           remember_me:
               lifetime: 86400
               domain:   ~
               path:     /
               key:      myKey
```

This is what I have now, even though the cookie is set, it doesn't work.

```
$um = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$member = $um->createUser();

… Form stuff with bindRequest etc.

$um->updatePassword($member);
$um->updateUser($member);

$providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$securityKey = 'myKey';

$token = new RememberMeToken($member, $providerKey, $securityKey,
$member->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

$redirectResponse = new RedirectResponse($url);
$redirectResponse->headers->setCookie(
   new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie(
       'REMEMBERME',
       base64_encode(implode(':', array($member->getUsername(),
$member->getPassword()))),
       time() + 60*60*24
   )
);
return $redirectResponse;
```

**Update:**

I've also tried working with the
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices class with reflection but it does not work. a cookie gets set but it's not working

```
$token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

$providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$securityKey = 'myKey';

$persistenService = new
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(array($um), $providerKey,
$securityKey, array('path' => '/', 'name' => 'REMEMBERME', 'domain' =>
null, 'secure' => false, 'httponly' => true,
'lifetime' => 86400));
$persistenService->setTokenProvider(new InMemoryTokenProvider());

$method = new \ReflectionMethod('Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices',
'onLoginSuccess');
 $method->setAccessible(true);
$method->invoke($persistenService, $request, $redirectResponse, $token);
```

I'm using Symfony v2.0.5 and FOSUserBundle 1.0

UPDATE 2:

I've tried a 3rd way. The same as above but without reflection:

```
$token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

$providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$securityKey = 'myKey';

$persistenService = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(array($um), $providerKey, $securityKey, array('path' => '/', 'name' => 'REMEMBERME', 'domain' => null, 'secure' => false, 'httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 31536000, 'always_remember_me' => true, 'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'));
$persistenService->setTokenProvider(new InMemoryTokenProvider());

$persistenService->loginSuccess($request, $redirectResponse, $token);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are setting the rememberme cookie directly, you have to use the following format:

```
base64_encode(<classname>:base64_encode(<username>):<expiry-timestamp>:<hash>)
```

where the hash will be:

```
sha256(<classname> . <username> . <expiry-timestamp> . <password> . <key>)
```

the key is the key you have entered in your security(.xml/.yml) in the `remember_me` section.

This is taken from `processAutoLoginCookie()` method in the <kbd>Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeService.php</kbd> file.

This is all done by the `generateCookieValue()` method in the same class.

However, I would not recommend on using doing it this way directly, but try to see if you can call the `TokenBasedRememberMeService::onLoginSuccess()` method, which sets this cookie for you to make the code more robust and portable.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I did it. I'm not using the FOSUserBundle and I'm using Doctrine Entity User Provider, but it should be trivial to adjust to your needs. Here is a general solution:

```
// after registration and persisting the user object to DB, I'm logging the user in automatically
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());

// but you can also get the token directly, if you're user is already logged in
$token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

// write cookie for persistent session storing
$providerKey = 'main'; // defined in security.yml
$securityKey = 'MySecret'; // defined in security.yml

$userProvider = new EntityUserProvider($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(), 'MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User', 'username');

$rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices(array($userProvider), $securityKey, $providerKey, array(
                'path' => '/',
                'name' => 'MyRememberMeCookie',
                'domain' => null,
                'secure' => false,
                'httponly' => true,
                'lifetime' => 1209600, // 14 days
                'always_remember_me' => true,
                'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me')
            );

$response = new Response();
$rememberMeService->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);

// further modify the response
// ........

return $response;
```

Just remember you have to set `always_remember_me option` to `true` (like I did in the code above) or have it in your $_POST parameters somehow, otherwise method `isRememberMeRequested` of `AbstractRememberMeServices` will return false and the cookie won't be stored.

You were pretty close to the correct solution though :) What you did wrong (in the 3rd attempt) is that you've changed the order of parameters here:

```
$persistenService = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(array($um), $providerKey, $securityKey, array('path' => '/', 'name' => 'REMEMBERME', 'domain' => null, 'secure' => false, 'httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 31536000, 'always_remember_me' => true, 'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'));
```

Take a look at `__construct()` in `AbstractRememberMeServices.php`. You should pass a `$securityKey` as 2nd argument and `$providerKey` as 3rd argument, not the other way around like you did by mistake ;)

What I don't know yet, is how to get parameters from security.yml directly in the controller not to duplicate it. By using `$this->container->getParameter()` I can get parameters stored under `parameters` key in config.yml, but not the ones places higher in the configuration tree. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: For getting cookie parameters in security.yml and avoid duplicates, you should put them in parameters.yml and in security.yml call them with %your_parameter_name%. They are now available in security and in parameters

Comment: +1 For using the Symfony2 security classes for this. Keep in mind that the default cookie name for remember-me cookies is `REMEMBERME`. Only if you use the same cookie name as the firewall you are authenticating against your manual set cookie will be recognized by the security listener.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given I got that D:

Comment: Fixed by just sending in doctrine without entitymanager. So basically $this->getDoctrine() only, thanks :) Now I need to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest solution was extend a BaseTokenBasedRememberMeServices and let it handle

```
namespace AppBundke\Security\Http;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices as BaseTokenBasedRememberMeServices;


class TokenBasedRememberMeServices extends BaseTokenBasedRememberMeServices
{
     protected $options_new = array('name' => 'REMEMBERME', 'domain' => null, 'path' => '/');

     public function __construct($userProvider, $secret, $providerKey, array $options = array(), LoggerInterface $logger = null)
     {
          return parent::__construct(array($userProvider), $secret, $providerKey, array_merge($this->options_new, $options));
     }

     public function generateCookie($user, $username, $expires, $password)
     {
        $cookie = new Cookie(
             $this->options['name'],
             parent::generateCookieValue(get_class($user), $username, $expires, $password),
             $expires,
             $this->options['path'],
             $this->options['domain'],
             $this->options['secure'],
             $this->options['httponly']
        );
    return $cookie;
    }
}
```

and in controller;

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$providerKey = $this->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$secret = $this->getParameter('secret');
$cookie_life_time = $this->getParameter('cookie_life_time');

$remember_me_service = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices($user, $secret, $providerKey );
$remember_me_cookie = $remember_me_service->generateCookie($user, $user->getUsername(),(time() + $cookie_life_time), $user->getPassword());
```

then response set cookie to $remember_me_cookie

I hope its works with you 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to set REMEMBERME cookie an User after a connection by token, using [Guard Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/guard_authentication.html).

In this situation I had no Response object to be able to use $response->headers->setCookie() and needs to use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)().
And in this situation, create a RedirectResponse is not appropriate.

This needs to be refactored but I post the raw procedural on which I based my service

```
$expires = time() + 2628000;
$hash = hash_hmac(
    'sha256',
     get_class($user).$user->getUsername().$expires.$user->getPassword(), 'secret in parameters.yml'
);
$value = base64_encode(implode(':', [get_class($user), base64_encode($user->getUsername()), $expires, $hash]));
setcookie(
    'REMEMBERME',
    $value,
    $expires,
    '/',
    'host',
    'ssl boolean',
    true
);
```